# MySQL workbench : How to export specific columns as update statement?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mysql-workbench

i want to export specific column with update statement, but in mysql workbench i found just insert statement.

Thanks

Comment: `UPDATE` requires a `WHERE` clause to specify which row to update. How is Export supposed to know what criteria to use?

Comment: ID is one of specific column to export

Comment: 'i want to export specific column with update statement' - I have no idea what this means ,can you expand please with examples.

Comment: ex : a table person with 5 column, i want to export just two specific column but in sql file exported, i want to get it with update statement :
**UPDATE PERSON SET NAME = TEST WHERE ID = 1**

Answer (score 0):

Solution :

1. create sql request to show all specific column with data **SELECT**
2. click on **export** on the bottom not on top
3. change Type d'exportation to **update**
4. execute (now you have an sql file with specific columns as update statement)

[image: PMA Workbench]

[image: PMA Workbench Settings]

Answer (score 0):

To export specific data from MySQL Workbench you may need to select Table Data Export Wizard.

There's also section advance where you could specific query
Please have a look on [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-admin-export-import-table.html)

[image]